# Visualforce error related to effective dated currency

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Question:Create a Visual force page which displays a variety of output fields**

Error:

> Currency fields on entities with effective dated currency are not
>   supported.

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Details">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Name }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Amount }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an 8 year old "Known Issue" [Display currency fields in VF pages when advanced currency management is enabled](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007kScAAI):

> Currently SF does not support displaying currency fields in
>   Visualforce pages when advanced currency management is enabled:
>   "ERROR: Currency Fields on entities with effective dated currency are
>   not supported" This is a major limitation as it prevents us from being
>   able to generate quotes using Visualforce pages. On one hand we must
>   be able to use the advanced currency option to support our sales reps
>   in the different regions and allow the usage of dated currency
>   conversion rates, and on the other hand we need to be able to create
>   quotes in Visualforce.

Google the exact error message "Currency fields on entities with effective dated currency are not supported" for some workarounds.

If you don't need "advanced currency management" turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

VisualForce Page not supporting field for currnecy. try to use below code.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity View">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{! Opportunity.Amount}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity View">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{! Opportunity.Amount}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>